# Check width before rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a div that gives a count of overflowed items something like this:
[item1] [item2] [+4]

where the +4 is the amount of items that couldn't fit into the div.

I've able to do this based on count but doing it based on width is tough.

Are there any ways to at render time see if a component is going to overflow it's parent div?

MY code so far is below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class ReciepesList extends Component {
  state = { elWidth: "" };
  componentDidMount() {
    //determineWidth();
  }

  determineWidth() {
    var inwidth = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.inner).getBoundingClientRect()
      .width;
    var inheight = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.inner).getBoundingClientRect()
      .height;
    var outwidth = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.outer).getBoundingClientRect()
      .width;
    var outheight = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
      this.refs.outer
    ).getBoundingClientRect().height;
    console(
      "inW",
      inwidth,
      "outW",
      outwidth,
      "inH",
      inheight,
      "outH",
      outheight
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { reciepes, all, style } = this.props;
    let count = 0;
    return (
      <div ref="outer">
        <div ref="inner" style={{ overflowY: "hidden" }}>
          {reciepes.map(reciepe => {
            //NEED SOLUTION HERE TO CHECK WIDTH
            if (count < 6 || all) {
              count++;
              return (
                <Button type="dashed" key={reciepe}>
                  {reciepe}
                </Button>
              );
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })}

          {reciepes.length - count > 0 && (
            <Button type="dashed">+{reciepes.length - count}</Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReciepesList;
```

Comment: compare the width of component to the width of the parent, if it's greater, it will overflow

Comment: Yes but how?  If I have an array of objects looking to make a list of them. How can i check before rendering against the parent?

Comment: can you post your code or make a fiddle, it will be much easier to help you?

Comment: @fila90,  I Edited my post I didn't get far best I had to do was implement a hard count :/

Comment: you can't calculate that there because `Button` is not rendered jet.

Here's fiddle with what you want, just simplified http://jsfiddle.net/vgzpnakt/1/

Now just put that logic in `componentDidMount` hook and you should be all set.

Comment: @fila90 thanks for the code but I alreayd have that part figured out. I guess the big issue is, if I change the ui. I would create an infinite loops of rerendering.

For visual purposes here's what Im trying to do. {} is the wrapper [] are divs.:

{[cake][carrot][rice]}[apple][blueberry]

to

{[cake][carrot][+3]}

Comment: sorry, I don't understand anymore what are you trying to do here.